# How to avoid hash sign in URL, using react-router-dom and react-router-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap, react-router-bootstrap

I'm using `<Route />` from `react-router-dom` for routing and `Nav` + `LinkContainer` from `react-bootstrap` + `react-router-bootstrap` for navigation:

```
//...
  <Route path="/shop/" component={Shop} />
//...
  <NavItem caption="Home" path="/" />
  <NavItem caption="Shop" path="/shop" />
//...
    
// with a helper component: 
const NavItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <LinkContainer to={props.path} > 
      <Nav.Link> {props.caption} </Nav.Link> 
    </LinkContainer>
  )
}
```

This creates an URL with a hash sign in it, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/shop
```

Where does this come from, what is it good for? Everything is working fine anyway, but this hash sign isn't smart, I think. Can I avoid it?

Comment: react router 4?

Comment: my version is 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> BrowserRouter

Instead of

> HashRouter

which prevents the showing # on URL.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  ...
}

instead of

import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yeeaah, works, thanks a lot!!
Can you tell me, what HashRouter vs BrowserRouter is about?

Comment: Hash Router is used when we use any backend framework template to load react build files and Browser Router is used for normal use when we host backend and frontend seperately.